# Can you access Company Profile information through Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was looking at a setting from [Get-MSOLCompanyInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolcompanyinformation?view=azureadps-1.0) - hoping to get the company's ReleaseTrack through an API.
[image: Image showing Release Track from Get-MSOLInformation]

I am somewhat guessing this would be part of the company "State" from the Get-MSOLCompanyInformation documentation, but I don't really see any graph-scopes that seem applicable

Anyone know which permission and endpoint I would query for that value?

Answer (score 0):

The nearest similar MS Graph API for  `Get-MSOLCompanyInformation` cmdlet  would be [organizations resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1).

**Sample Request:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Get-MgOrganization" Cmdlet

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgorganization?view=graph-powershell-beta

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).